# MySQL java database. Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a java-database. I am using IntelliJ and eclipse. Here is what I receive in eclipse:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1750)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:298)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:81)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

And here is what I receive in IntelliJ:

```
    Connection to MySQL - QSAR@localhost failed
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1709)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
  in RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:27)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.connect(Unknown Source)
  in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:269)
```

I have used database name: data; and here is its URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data 
I have used driver file.
MySQL server instance is running.
But it still doesn't work.
I can't find any solutions. Help me, please.

Comment: I think you need to look closely at the first line of you message, where it says 'Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'. Check your credentials.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP doesn't seem to have read the error message.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 1):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

check, does this `user` really exists in your `mysql/users` table and have crypted password? Try to reload your user DB privileges. Check the row in `mysql/db` table for `data` database and this user.